# Prove/disprove that every undirected finite graph $G = (V,E)$ with $n$ vertices $ \forall v \in V$ : $deg(v) \ge 1$ is a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

An edge is associated with two vertices.

I try to contradict it by saying that the graph is disconnected.

Using handshaking lemma,in the graph there is at least $\frac{n}{2}$ edges.

There is $k\ge2$ connected components, so exists a connected component that has at most $\frac{n}{k}$ vertices.

I don't know how to continue...

How can I prove it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you stated the problem well? Because why not having a graph with $4$ vertices creating two connected components, such that every vertex $v$ has $deg(v)=1$?

Comment: Clearly the statement is wrong on its own. Indeed, as Mesmerized student points out, this property is stable by putting two graphs next to each other, forming a disconnected graph

Answer (score 1):

Given vertices $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ (where $n \ge 4$), form a graph with two connected components, where the first component is the edge $v_1 v_2$ and the second component is a path graph $v_3, \ldots, v_n$.  Due to this counterexample, the given statement is false if $|V| \ge 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the graph $G$ with $V = \{1,2,3,4,...,2n-1,2n\}$ and connect $1\sim 2$, $3\sim 4$, $5\sim 6$, . . . $(2n-1)\sim2n$, then $\deg(v) \geq 1$ for all $v$ but $G$ is not connected.